# HttpWebRequest slows down with increased thread count

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I've been trying to download some data in parallel using HttpWebRequest. In order to do it, I start some threads. However, despite very high bandwidth, I've noticed that the effective download speed decreases when the thread count exceed 4. When I use multiple processes, the issue vanishes.

How can I improve my download speed within a single process?

Regards,
RSuthke

Comment: are you using dedicated threads or the thread pool?

Comment: Are you making all requests to the same server?

Comment: I'm using dedicated threads and I make all the requests to the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you have more threads than cores, you're going to have threads that are interrupted. Thread switching is going to kill your performance. I'd try using the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx) (assuming that you are using .Net 4.0) or a thread pool at the very least.

Comment: Downloading files is not CPU-intensive task, so thread switching shouldn't affect performance.